# AS3 How to check if BitmapData is empty

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, bitmapdata, erase

I have a code to erase a masked movieclip. (credits [here](http://f6design.com/journal/2009/05/24/erase-an-image-using-your-mouse-in-as3/))
I would like to know how I can check if the whole movieclip is been erased.
So I thought I had to check if the BitmapData is empty, but I could be terribly wrong!
How can I check if every pixel of the movieclip has been erased?
Of course my example below is wrong, but I think it has to be something like that.

```
if (erasableBitmapData = empty)
    { 
    trace("empty")
    }
```

---

```
    var lineSize:Number=40;
    var doDraw:Boolean=false;
    var resumeDrawing:Boolean=false;

    var erasableBitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(700, 500, true, 0xFFFFFFFF);
    var erasableBitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(erasableBitmapData);
    erasableBitmap.cacheAsBitmap = true;
    addChild(erasableBitmap);

    maskee.cacheAsBitmap = true;
    maskee.mask = erasableBitmap;

    var eraserClip:Sprite = new Sprite();
    initEraser();
    function initEraser():void {
        eraserClip.graphics.lineStyle(lineSize,0xff0000);
        eraserClip.graphics.moveTo(stage.mouseX,stage.mouseY);
    }

    var drawnBitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(700, 500, true, 0x00000000);
    var drawnBitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(drawnBitmapData);

    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,maskMove);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, maskOut); 
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER,maskOver);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,startDrawing);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,stopDrawing);

    function startDrawing(e:MouseEvent):void {
        eraserClip.graphics.moveTo(stage.mouseX,stage.mouseY);
        doDraw=true;
    }

    function stopDrawing(e:MouseEvent):void {
        doDraw=false;
        resumeDrawing = false;
    }

    function maskOut(e:Event):void {
        if (doDraw){
            resumeDrawing = true;
        }
    }

    function maskOver(e:MouseEvent):void {
        if (resumeDrawing){
            resumeDrawing = false;
            eraserClip.graphics.moveTo(stage.mouseX,stage.mouseY);
        }
    }

    function maskMove(e:MouseEvent):void {
        if (doDraw && !resumeDrawing){
            eraserClip.graphics.lineTo(stage.mouseX,stage.mouseY);
            drawnBitmapData.fillRect(drawnBitmapData.rect, 0x00000000); 
            drawnBitmapData.draw(eraserClip , new Matrix(), null, BlendMode.NORMAL);
            erasableBitmapData.fillRect(erasableBitmapData.rect, 0xFFFFFFFF);
            erasableBitmapData.draw(drawnBitmap, new Matrix(), null, BlendMode.ERASE);
        }
            e.updateAfterEvent();
    }


    reset_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,reset);

    function reset(e:Event):void {
        eraserClip.graphics.clear();
        initEraser();
        erasableBitmapData.fillRect(erasableBitmapData.rect, 0xFFFFFFFF);
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check if [`getColorBoundsRect`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#getColorBoundsRect%28%29) returns an rectangle with an width and height of `0` for the colour you consider as 'empty', setting the `findColor` argument to false. There are other ways to do this, but this is at least many times faster than checking every single pixel.

The default value of true for the `findColor` argument gives you an rectangle that encloses all pixels for those `(pixelColor & mask) == emptyColor` is true. When dealing with alpha values, a mask of `0xFF000000` can be used to ignore rbg values of a pixel and to only check its alpha value. So the mask `0xFF000000` and the colour `0xFF000000` would match all fully opaque pixels, while the mask `0xFF000000` and the colour `0x00000000` would match all fully transparent pixels. As [meddlingwithfire](https://stackoverflow.com/users/682608/meddlingwithfire) pointed out, this won't do the job here. By setting `findColor` to false, this process is kind of reversed so that the rectangle will enclose all pixels that are *not* using the empty colour. For bitmaps containing no other colours, the result will be a rectangle with an area of `0`.

```
var maskColor:uint = 0xFF000000;
var emptyColor:uint = 0x00000000;
var bounds:Rectangle = erasableBitmapData.getColorBoundsRect(maskColor, emptyColor, false);
if (bounds.width == 0 && bounds.height == 0){
    trace("empty"); // no visible pixels
}
```

Technically there is a difference between a black transparent pixel `0x00000000` and for example a red transparent pixel `0x00FF0000` - but there is no visible difference (both are invisible) so you should ignore the rgb values completely, as I did in the example by using that particular mask.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I tried a lot of things, is this in the right direction?                                                                            -------------------------------------                        

var colorBoundsRect:Rectangle = erasableBitmapData.getColorBoundsRect(0x00FFFFFF, 0x00FF0000, true);
if (colorBoundsRect.? = 0){ trace("empty");}

Comment: Thank you, your explanation is very understandable and clear. I get a 1152 error, for; 'var mask. Could this be because I already used 'mask' in this line of code; maskee.mask = erasableBitmap; ?

Comment: @Opoe No, a property with the same name is fine. That error indicates that there is some problem with inheritance. Or maybe you have an object on stage which is named 'mask'. That's a very strange error to occur on a simple variable declaration.

Comment: mask was considered as reserved so I changed it to mask1. I don't get anymore errors, but it doesnt trace anything yet. I'll try some more, still learning!

Comment: i've been trying several things with this code because I can't get it to work. I think because it draws the erased lines to a sprite. the 'var EraserClip' part. Could it have anyhting to do with that?

Comment: I think it's something in `maskMove`, I don't see why  `erasableBitmapData` is filled with `0xFFFFFFFF` every move. Does it work the way you want it (besides what you asked in the question's title)? If not maybe you should open another question. The comments here aren't good to discuss things or to find errors, a new question may be better for that.

Comment: You're probably right, the code functions exactly like this demo http://bit.ly/b2O7kg

Answer (score 1):

Create a baseline "empty" BitmapData instance.  Use that BitmapData's compare method, passing in your "potentially empty" BitmapData.  You'll get a new BitmapData reference that has the pixel differences between the two.  Using that new BitmapData reference, you can access the histogram method to get a list of all the counts for every channel.  If the empty BitmapData instance and the "potentially empty" BitmapData instance are exactly the same, then your histogram channel will have the total number of pixels in your BitmapData as the count in the zero index of each channel (since the BitmapData difference in the case of equal data would be filled with 0x00000000 pixels).

Should be relatively quick too, as you can rely on the AS engine to look at each pixel as opposed to having to manually call the expensive getPixel() method.

Using the color bounds approach can lead to false-positives.  If your bitmaps are the same in the upper-left and lower-left positions then your color bounds rect will encompass the entire area, even though all of the pixels in-between could be completely different.

Answer (score 1):

The `BitmapData.compare(BitmapData)` function returns either a new `BitmapData` containing the difference between the the calling two `BitmapData`s, or if the `BitmapData` objects are equivalent (with the same width, height, and identical pixel values), the method returns the number 0. Meaning you could use the following to check if a `DisplayObject` contains graphics

```
var eraseableBitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(264,864,true,0xFFFFFFFF);
//initialise the eraseableBitmapData
eraseableBitmapData.draw(someDisplayOject)
//draw your object's bitmap data

var emptyBitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(264,864,true,0xFFFFFFFF);
//create an identical but empty BitmapData object

if( erasableBitmapData.compare ( emptyBitmapData ) == 0 ) {
    trace("empty");//object is completely empty
} else {
    trace("not empty");//object still has stuff in
}
```

[draw() documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#draw%28%29)

[compare() documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#compare%28%29)

Comment: Thank you, Kris! I'll try this answer as soon as possible and let you know how it went :)

Comment: It didn't work, I think it's because I'm using a mask to 'relocate' the erased pixels, what do you think?